# Reference request: complex half spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, terminology

For real spaces, the notion of a half space is well-known. It's given by
the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, \mid \, y^\top x \leq b \}$ for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. For the space $\mathbb{C}^n$, a half-space should be the following
$$\{ x \in \mathbb{C}^n \, | \, \text{Re}(y^\text{H} x) \leq b \},$$
where $y \in \mathbb{C}^n$, and $(\cdot)^\text{H}$ denotes the conjugate transpose. However, I cannot find any mention of this in the literature. Am I perhaps using the wrong terminology? For example, this post: [Regarding closed half spaces in $\mathbb{C}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725065/regarding-closed-half-spaces-in-mathbbcn), mentions closed complex half-spaces, but I am unable to find the mentioned paper.

Comment: Use `$\{ x\mid \varphi(x)\}$` for $\{ x\mid \varphi(x)\}$.

Comment: Your complex half-space is the usual half-space with respect to the real inner product induced from the complex one. So perhaps authors would just keep the term "half-space"?

Comment: Your definition and terminology seems to tally with that used [here](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/func-an-2007-2008/lcvs-5.pdf) for topological vector spaces over $\ \Bbb{R}\ $ or $ \Bbb{C}\ $:

"Suppose $\ \mathcal{X}\ $ is a vector space, equipped with a linear topology $\ \mathfrak{T}\ $. A subset $\ \mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{X}\ $ is said to be a $\ \mathfrak{T}$-*closed half-space in* $\ \mathcal{X}\ $, if there exist $\ \phi\in(\mathcal{X},\mathfrak{T})^*\ $ and $\ s\in\Bbb{R}\ $, such that
$\ \mathcal{H}=$$\,\{x\in\mathcal{X}\ :$$\,\ \text{Re}\,\phi(x)\le$$\, s\}\ $."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of a complex half-space coincides with what is used in the literature to formulate separation theorems (Hahn-Banach theorems): That is, separation of sets by half-spaces. See, e.g., Rudin, Functional analysis, Chapter 3. There exactly these sets are used, without calling them explicitly complex half spaces.